# I get the same error on terminal for different file

Tags: ruby, terminal, cucumber

I am running a feature file on Cucumber and every-time I get the same error message. No matter what feature file tags I run.

> Missing Examples section for Scenario Outline at
>   features/support/internetonly.feature:10
>   (Cucumber::Core::Gherkin::ParseError)

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message speaks for itself: you have scenario outline without examples table. Either include examples table, either replace `Scenario Outline:` with just `Scenario:`.